# iOS: Need help figuring out this crash "Crashed: NSOperationQueue Serial Queue EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

This is the crash report I received from crashlytics and I don't have the slightest clue on what it means or what to do about this. Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
 Thread : Crashed: NSOperationQueue Serial Queue
 0  libsystem_platform.dylib       0x3baef4da _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Swift + 185
 1  ???                            0x0000000c 
 2  DataDetectorsCore              0x350b26bb DDTokenCacheGetItemAtIndexCreateIfNeeded + 90
 3  DataDetectorsCore              0x350b2635 DDTokenCacheGetTokensAtPosition + 1084
 4  DataDetectorsCore              0x350ae41d _DDScannerHandleState + 472
 5  DataDetectorsCore              0x350aea71 _DDScannerHandleState + 2092
 6  DataDetectorsCore              0x350addf1 DDScannerScanQuery + 328
 7  DataDetectorsUI                0x350c8f7d -[DDOperation main] + 288
 8  Foundation                     0x31664aa5 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 772
 9  Foundation                     0x3170896d __NSOQSchedule_f + 60
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b9c5e7b _dispatch_queue_drain + 374
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b9c2f93 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 42
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b9c6745 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 76
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b9c69c5 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3baf0dff _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

Comment: well you have de-referenced a NULL pointer somehow... look at the top of the stack trace, try to figure out where you are doing that in the code referenced in the top stack frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any part of your app where the user clicks on a URL or specifies a URL which is then handled by your app, or by the system on behalf of your app.  The subsystem that does this is DataDetectorsCore.

If you have code around that area, it would be a good idea to add log messages, assert checks, validation, and unit test code.

It might be that you are receiving maliciously crafted URLs; here is an example but for the Mac platform: http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/02/06/anatomy-of-a-bug-how-mac-os-x-chokes-if-you-type-file/